# Laravel DB transactions with multiple commits?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, transactions

Can I make some checkpoints during DB transaction?

For example, when the transaction starts, I have many queries, updates, deletes and so on.

```
DB::transaction(function () {
    DB::table('users')->update(['votes' => 1]);
    // something else here
    DB::table('posts')->delete();
});
```

As far as I understand, this kind of function would automatically commit everything in case of success and rollback if something goes wrong.

But would it be possible not to rollback everything in case of error, for example, like

```
DB::table('users')->update(['votes' => 1]);
// something else here
DB::if_successful_so_far_do_not_rollback_previous_lines();
DB::table('posts')->delete();
```

Do any "small inner commits" exist?

Comment: Why don#t you split it up in two commits then? :)

Comment: I try to use as few connections as I can

Comment: Well, I think that'd be the only solution. I don't think that you can just "partly rollback" a transaction.

Comment: Your question is a bit funny because you basically need 2 commits and want to achieve it using only one. No, **you have to use 2 commits and end of story**.

Comment: This is like buying a rocket to get to your home form work, then you actually use the car of the salesman who sold you the rocket.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you can. But this also depends on the database you are using.

Laravel supports nested transactions. Which is something close to what you need.

To isolate an inner transaction, you have to wrap it inside a try-catch block. So if the inner transaction throws an exception, it will not reach the outer transaction, therefore continuing the process. But if the outer transaction throws an Exception, the whole transaction (including its nested transactions) will roll back.

So you will end up with something like this:

```
public function testNestedTransactions()
{

    $user = EloquentTestUser::create(['email' => 'taylor@laravel.com']);

    $this->connection()->transaction(function () use ($user) {

        try {
            $this->connection()->transaction(function () use ($user) {
                $user->email = 'otwell@laravel.com';
                $user->save();
                throw new Exception;
            });
        } catch (Exception $e) {}

        $user = EloquentTestUser::first();
        $this->assertEquals('taylor@laravel.com', $user->email);

    });

}
```

This is a test written by Otwell in [this commit implementing the functionality of nested transactions in Laravel](https://github.com/laravel/framework/commit/9957329279fced0a24ac3d9d02cfe99407fa8f54#diff-2b6eae4ede78d520041c54df36afb408R453). He first create an user, then start a transaction with a nested transaction where he updates the user email and then throws an exception (meaning an error has ocurred). Right under it, he checks if the user email stills the same when he created it, and it does, because the nested transaction has rolled back, but the outer transaction stills going.